# Git bisect rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Can `git bisect` be used in auto-mode with rails?

The docs for `git bisect` shows how it can be used with the Linux kernel `git bisect run make`

For rails, this should be `git bisect bundle exec rake spec`. But how to know when there's an error for bisect? Since RSpec is ultimately enveloped in Bundler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rake will return with a non-zero exit code when it did not run successfully, and this is what git bisect will use to determine if there was a bug.

Now, if your tests didn't catch the bug, then git bisect won't help --- because each time it runs, the rake will return clean.

So, you may want to write a test that is outside of source control to run against, and find when it first started to fail.